# Default Cyrillic locale for input in EditText

Tags: android

I ran into a problem with default locale/language in EditText. 
The default keyboard language does not match the system language and locale
`Locale.getDefault() // "russian"`  For text input cyrillic i need to switch the language English->Russian. Reading the documentation I could not find how to set the default keyboard language. I hope you give me an explanation in this regard.)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android/2900144#2900144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that is not possible.

You are trying to force the user to input only in russian.
You shouldn't do that because of the user experience.
Also, the language may not be installed on the user's keyboard and that may lead to the crash.